# date filtering with advanced criteria

Tags: excel

I have an advanced filter that runs on my Excel VBA application which is suppose to filter dates in the data base, I created the advance filter on the worksheet and it works fine except for when it comes to filtering dates this is the formula I'm using:

```
=IF(C5="",">1","<=" &C5)  start date

=IF(C5="","<60000","<" &C5) end date
```

I tried removing the Quotes fron the <60000 but received a error.
the filter will not filter the dates requested. For example I ask to filter date between 9/20/2018 and 9/30/2018 and get results outside those dates as well as the dates requested.

If I ask for records to be show on a specific date say 9/29/2018 I get to see those dates or if I ask to see dates between 1/5/2019 and 2/15/2019 I see those.
Ialso get for example I ask for dates between 5/1/2016 and 5/30/2016 I get dates of 4/30/2016 included.

Comment: I think the *start date* should be `=IF(C5="",">1",">=" &C5) ` (*greater than or equal to C5*)

Comment: I tried that and the result was no data filtered. I even removed the = sign and what I got was dates before the ones I was filtering ex. filtered for 5/2/2016 to 5/19/2016 got the 5/1 to 5/19 but also got 4/30/2016 also.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different method for your criteria.

Assuming:

- your column of Dates has a header of **Dates**
- your criteria range is `A1:B2`
- `startDt` and `endDt` refer to the obvious

---

```
A1:=  Dates
B1:=  Dates
A2:= =">="&MAX(1,startDt)
B2:= ="<" &MIN(endDt,1000000)
```

If you want to include the actual *End Date* (unlike your formula), then change the formula in `B2`

```
B2:= ="<=" &MIN(endDt,99999)
```

[image]